# How to do drag and drop in lightning components?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am trying to drag and drop images from one block into another and if in the block an image is already present then those images must get swaped

Comment: Can you please post the code which you've tried along with the question? @Akarsh

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok Akarsh I hope the below code will fulfil your requirement.

While dragging I'm saving the element id and its parent elements id in startid and parentid. Now i am creating a new document fragment which contains the element thats being dragged and appending the fragment to event.target.id

Component

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable">
    <aura:attribute name="startId" type="string"/>
    <aura:attribute name="parentId" type="string"/>

    <div class="div1" id="div1" ondrop="{!c.drop}" ondragover="{!c.allowDrop}">
        <img src="{!$Resource.Pic1}" draggable="true" ondragstart="{!c.drag}" id="drag1" width="88" height="31"/>
    </div>

    <div class="div2" id="div2" ondrop="{!c.drop}" ondragover="{!c.allowDrop}">
        <img src="{!$Resource.Pic2}" draggable="true" ondragstart="{!c.drag}" id="drag2" width="88" height="31"/>
    </div>
    <input type="button" onclick="{!c.MoveDiv}" value="Click Me" />
    <div class="div2" id="div3" ondrop="{!c.drop}" ondragover="{!c.allowDrop}"><span id="drag3"> </span></div>

</aura:component>
```

Controller

```
({
    allowDrop: function(cmp, event, helper){
        event.preventDefault();
    },
    drag: function(cmp, ev, helper){
          var parentId = document.getElementById(ev.target.id).parentElement.id;
        cmp.set("v.startId",ev.target.id);
        cmp.set("v.parentId",parentId);
    },
    drop: function(cmp, ev, helper){
        var drag = cmp.get("v.startId");
        var div = ev.target.id;
        var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
        fragment.appendChild(document.getElementById(drag));
        document.getElementById(div).appendChild(fragment);
        var c = document.getElementById(div).children;
        var x = document.getElementById('drag1').parentElement.id;
        var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
        fragment.appendChild(document.getElementById(c[0].id));
        document.getElementById(cmp.get("v.parentId")).appendChild(fragment);
    }
})
```

Style

```
.THIS.div1 {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.THIS.div2 {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Can you describe the working?
Code without explanation is considered bad.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal While dragging I'm saving the element id and its parent elements id in startid and parentid. Now i am creating a new document fragment which contains the element thats being dragged and appending the fragment to event.target.id